# How to convert timestamp to 24 hours SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, timestamp

I have this query, how to convert timestamp 12 to 24 hours?

```
select 
    os.no_order_survey  as 'id',
    os.id_finance_company  as 'group_fin', 
    os.created_at as 'order',
    hs.created_at as 'after_order' , 
    concat('')  as 'result_second_from_order_to_after'
from 
    tr_order_survey os 
join 
    tr_hasil_survey hs on os.no_order_survey = hs.no_order_survey 
order by 
    os.created_at desc
```

I want to change format after_order to 24 hours, and I want to find the difference between order and after order and avg from `result_second_from_order_to_after` grouped by group fin

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: using only text (no images) explain what you mean by "format after_order to 24 hours" (nb: I don't get to see imgur.com images due to network policy) so using my phone I saw yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss  in both columns. what do you expect to see if an **hs.created_at  = 2023-05-12 00:00:00** ? e.g. are you expecting **2023-05-11 24:00:00**?

 PLUS - **most important** - tell use **whch dbms** you use as the syntax IS different for each vendor

Comment: @jarlh dbms using mysql

Comment: Also, the timestamps showing up in the screenshot don't have 'AM' and 'PM' in it, so those timestamps seem to be in 24-hour format already. If e.g. the `2023-05-09 02:44:47` itself is supposed to be actually 2:44 PM, i.e. `2023-05-09 14:44:47` - then it seems to be the input handling issue. MySQL by default supports 24-hour times.